# Can't change to daylight savings time on Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I am trying to change turn on the Daylight Savings time setting on Xbox 360. I have disconnected from Xbox Live, restarted my system, and even disconnected from the WiFi, but the text is still grayed out.